# phonegap app installation error on windows phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am trying to install a phonegap/cordova app on windows phone 8 via Qr code.build remotely using

https://build.phonegap.com/

but when i tap to open app, i get an error that " there is a problem with this company app, please contact your company for help" and the application doesn't open, so I downloaded the .xap file, but got no clue how to run it, does one have to configure some settngs in the phone and where should I place this file in my phone???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your company for help?

Comment: what company?? I don't understand.. ,i downloaded the xap file placed in SD card, still the app store is not picking up the SD card option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install a .xap file on a Windows Phone, you must have a windows phone unlock for development. You can unlock it if you have a developer account. If you dont have it you must try it on a emulator